# Appending User Input into a string

Tags: java, string, append, addition

Im trying to append a string that users input into using global keypresses with an api I found. But I can't figure out how to add to the string without overwriting what is already there.

```
int i = 1;
public String log = "Write";
public String[] logger = new String[i];
public static PrintStream out = null;
public BufferedWriter writer = null;




    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        while(i<1000000000){

        logger[i] = NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
        i++;
        System.out.println(logger[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use StringBuilder class append method whenever you have to append characters or string to an existing variable.

```
StringBuilder strBuilder= new StringBuilder();
strBuilder.append("I am a bad programmer");
strBuilder.append("to use concatenation");
strBuilder.append("Instead of StringBuilder");
strBuilder.append(" or StringBuffer");
String str= strBuilder.toString();

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html
```

Comment: That link is not clickable. One has to paste it into the browser's address bar. Therefore I had edited it.